# C++11 range-based for on a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, gcc

I have just compiled GCC 4.6.0, and I wanted to try the new features out, starting with the range-based for loop.
The first loop I wanted to change was iterating on a std::vector of pointers. I changed the code to use the new syntax, but it didn't compile.

I have tried to substitute another for loop, which was on a std::vector of structs, and it compiled and ran perfectly.

Here is a short test code to show you my problem:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector< int > values;
    
    values.push_back(2);
    values.push_back(5);
    values.push_back(8);
    values.push_back(13);
    values.push_back(17);
    
    for (int &n : values)
    {
        std::cout << n << "\n";
    }
    
    std::vector< int* > pointers;
    
    pointers.push_back(new int(2));
    pointers.push_back(new int(5));
    pointers.push_back(new int(8));
    pointers.push_back(new int(13));
    pointers.push_back(new int(17));
    
    for ((int*) &p : values)
    {
        std::cout << (*p) << "\n";
    }
    
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < pointers.size(); ++i)
    {
        delete pointers[i];
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile it *(yes, I give -std=c++0x as a parameter to g++)*, it dies with this error:

> main.cpp|27|error: found ‘:’ in nested-name-specifier, expected ‘::’

If I comment the lines 27-30 out, it's OK.

What am I doing wrong? Isn't the pointer-reference declaring syntax right?
Or is there a limitation of contained types where range-based for loops can be used?

Comment: Should probably be moved to SO

Comment: @Doug: Agreed...and it would also help if the question included the source code definitely rather than having a tiny URL.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
for ((int*) &p : values)
```

This is wrong. `(int*)` is an expression alone, so you need to do `int*&` (with no parenthesis, that makes an expression - aka "not a type name") at least to make it correct. I prefer to use auto or auto&, personally.

You can do :

```
for (auto p : values) // here p is a pointer, a copy of each pointer
```

or

```
for (auto& p : values ) // here p is a non-const reference to a pointer
```

or

```
for ( int* p : values ) // here p is a copy of each pointer
```

or in generic code:

```
for ( auto&& p: values ) // p is either a const reference to what is in values, or a non-const reference, depends on the context
```

Comment: So `auto` in this case - on a `std::vector<int*>` - would yield `int*`, and `auto&` would yield `int*&`. Makes sense. Why would you ever want `int*&` though? Oh I guess the former is actually copying memory and the latter is not?

Comment: @Andrew Depends in the sitaution, maybe sometime you want to make sure the type you get is what you want, or maybe you want to imply a conversion in some ways. auto is a good default here, but then with a concept it's slightly better (C++20): `for( std::integral auto* p : values)` makes sur that you get pointers to something that appear to be an integral.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to iterate over 'pointers' instead of 'values' there...

Comment: Too bad that there can be only one answer accepted. You were right too, I was silly to write values instead of pointers, but Klaim's comment was more detailed, and showed the error with the parentheses. Anyway, thank you very much!